# Karate-UI: Using a variable in waitFor() to check the element in UI testing

Tags: karate, ui-testing

I am trying to make UI testing by Karate v0.9.5
In my case I use the waitFor() function like this

```
* def testName = 'name_' + (int)(Math.random()*100)
And input('input[name=title]', testName)
When click('{button/span}Add')
Then waitFor('{}#(testName)')
```

and it detect `#(testName)` as a string
Is there any way to use a variable in the waitFor() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the simplest way. Anything within the `( )` is treated as pure JavaScript.

```
Then waitFor('{}' + testName)
```