# Karate UI - how to wait till some element disappear ? like in selenium we have element visibility

Tags: automation, ui-automation, karate

Karate UI - how to wait till some element disappear ? like in selenium we have element visibility

Want wait till some element gets disappear (loading/spinner)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Karate-UI: Using a variable in waitFor() to check the element in UI testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649259/karate-ui-using-a-variable-in-waitfor-to-check-the-element-in-ui-testing)

Answer (score 3):

Using waitForResultCount() with an expected count of zero effectively does this:

```
* waitForResultCount('.spinner', 0)
```

https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/#waitforresultcount

Answer (score -2):

Check out the waitUntil function it might be what you are looking for https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/#waituntil